# How to login into smtp server

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, smtp

I want to login into an server **without sending any mail**.

Code for explanation:

```
Dim S As New SMTP()
Dim IsOk As Boolean
IsOk = S.Connect("smtp.example.com","994","username","password")
IF IsOk Then
    MsgBox("username, " & "you are logged in successfully.")
End If
```

What is the most efficient and fastest way to login into server without sending any mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. The [SmtpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) has no method that does only authentication. It only has methods for sending emails, when it comes to that.

If you don't mind tarnishing your soul, you could make sure your server is configured to reject emails without a sender address, then try sending an email without a sender (i.e.: don't populate the `From` property of the [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx)). It will try to connect, and if it does, it'll throw an Exception instead of sending the email. Just check that you're getting an empty sender related exception instead of an authentication one.

If you can't make sure the server is configured like that, though, you could learn the SMTP protocol and use some WCF to try and figure it out on your own. Happy coding!

P.S.: usually the login for a SMTP server is the same for its corresponding POP3/IMAP one. Couldn't you check those instead?